# Connection to ejabberd

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I am currently having an issue with my ejabberd server I've set up recently: Any client is unable to connect to the server. Whether it is Psi or a sample code from the net, all produce an error when it comes to connecting, even though both is located on my computer, so no network issues can be the reason.
I have so far tried to bind the listener to a different port, and also checked the values in the ejabberd.yml. However, I was not able to find a sulution for my problem.
The service log of the server was not conspicious either:

```
2015-12-28 18:16:29.923 [info] <0.7.0> Application oauth2 started on node ejabberd@localhost
2015-12-28 18:16:29.938 [info] <0.449.0>@ejabberd_listener:listen_tcp:189 Reusing listening port for {5222,{0,0,0,0},tcp}
2015-12-28 18:16:29.938 [info] <0.450.0>@ejabberd_listener:listen_tcp:189 Reusing listening port for {5269,{0,0,0,0},tcp}
2015-12-28 18:16:29.938 [info] <0.451.0>@ejabberd_listener:listen_tcp:189 Reusing listening port for {5280,{0,0,0,0},tcp}
2015-12-28 18:16:29.938 [info] <0.37.0>@ejabberd_app:start:75 ejabberd 15.11 is started in the node ejabberd@localhost
2015-12-28 18:16:29.938 [info] <0.7.0> Application ejabberd started on node ejabberd@localhost
```

Did I do something wrong when entering the parameters? Or is this a problem of configuration? My first idea was that my anti-virus avast might be blocking some of the traffic, but i couldn't find anything on the web about that.
Attached you can find screenshots of psi and the server-ui.
The host name is pc-michi

[image]
[image][image]

With this link you can view my .yml file:
http://workupload.com/file/rQoLIf4Y
Could you please tell me what goes wrong here?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like basic networking configuration issue. Psi client is not able to connect to the server. There may be multiple reasons:

- Firewall blocking port.
- Name of the machine you use to connect to cannot be resolve to proper IP address.

You should try connecting on that host on port 5222 from command-line, for example with telnet to check that you can open a TCP socket properly.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! I could solve the problem now: The firewall was ok, and telnet requests were answerd properly aswell. But as it seems, Psi does not like neither 'localhost' nor the name of the pc in the host field. However, when entering the standard ip 127.0.0.1 it connects without any of the issues mentioned above :)